# Azure DevOps (VSTS) - how to copy a file from the agent VM and into my repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

I'm very confused about how one of the build task currently works.

I have been using Grunt locally in VS-Code to minify a JS file. All seems to be working well. In Azure DevOps, as a Build Task, I am using the same package.json the minification takes place but on the agent VM:

```
D:\a\1\s\Build\Hello.js
```

Looking in my repo, this file does not exist. I am assuming that I need to copy the file and upload to my own repo. Does anyone know how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A build usually creates a build ** artifact** that gets copied to a drop location. You will use the build artifacts inside your release definitions to **deploy** the binaries / minified or optimized code to an environment.

You probably don't want/need to upload any file back to your repo.

See: [What is Azure pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines)

Comment: Thank you Martin. I thought that this would be the case. In essence, I have two directories: original and minified sources, I want to make the minified source after the Grunt task available in my repo. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you usually only have the original source within your repository and minify the code within your build task. Then you publish the build artifacts (minifed sources) and use it in a release definition to deploy it. You don't put it back into your repo.

Comment: Thank you Martin, you have answered my question.